# Print all print() in log file on exit

Tags: python-3.x, loops, logfiles

I have a script with a print in a while loop.
This loop is running for like 10 hours and print something every minute or so.
I would like to store all print() outputs in a single log file
I don't know how to proceed
I use windows and Python 3.6

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: have you considered the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)?

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[print](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) can send the output to a file. Just provide a file descriptor:

```
for i in range(10): # or a `while` loop
    with open('mylog.log', 'a') as f:
        print("h0i", file=f)
```